# How to show a card with an image stored on the SD card?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've used Android Monitor to put my own images into the DCIM directory on the sdcard, but by default Glass does not show any cards with the new images stored in that directory. How would I display cards with all images in a directory on the sdcard?

One partial solution to this question that I found is to send the images/videos from another Google+ account to your Glass. This way all the images/videos show up. However, this is really an unacceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The cards you watch in your timeline are posted using the Mirror API (you can do this through a Glass app also).
So, when you take a picture with you glasses, It actually insert the new card in your timeline.

If you put your pictures directly to you SD, Glasses doesn't know that and can't post the item to you timeline.

The timeline is designed to notify the user of notifications, but not for use as a gallery. In fact only last for 7 days or until a maximum of 200 cards.

From developers guide:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/static-cards

> When Glassware inserts static cards into the timeline, Glass may play a notification sound to alert users. All previous static cards also shift to the right and disappear from the timeline after 7 days or when 200 cards are newer